# A ListView where a specific row can always be scrolled to the top?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to be able to take a `ListView` and have a specific row be scrollable to the top of that `Listview's` bounds, even if the row is near the end and normally wouldn't be able to scroll that high in a normal android `ListView` (similar to how twitter works when you drill into a specific tweet and that tweet is always scrollable to the top even when there's nothing underneath it.)

Is there any way I can accomplish this task easily? I've tried measuring the row i want to scroll to the top and applying bottom padding to account for the extra space it would need, but that yields odd results (i presume because changing padding and such during the measure pass of a view is ill advised). Doing so before the measure pass doesn't work since the measured height of the cell in question (and any cells after it) hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Do You mean to scroll last element of list to be on top of screen to have empty space below it?

Comment: Yeah, that's what i need to do.

Comment: It's pretty hacky, but... Add an empty [footer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) to the end of the list that's the size of the screen?

Comment: I have no idea how to use this method, but it looks helpful: [View.overScrollBy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#overScrollBy%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: looks promising, i'll look into it. Thanks @NeilTraft!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out; its a bit complex but it seems to work mostly:

```
public int usedHeightForAndAfterDesiredRow() {
    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < rowHeights.size(); index++) {
        int height = rowHeights.get(rowHeights.keyAt(index));
        totalHeight += height;
    }
    return totalHeight;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    if (measuringLayout.getLayoutParams() == null) {
        measuringLayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight()));
    }

    // measure the row ahead of time so that we know how much space will need to be added at the end
    if (position >= mainRowPosition && position < getCount()-1 && rowHeights.indexOfKey(position) < 0) {
        measuringLayout.addView(view, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        measuringLayout.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        rowHeights.put(position, view.getMeasuredHeight());
        measuringLayout.removeAllViews();

        view.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    if (position == getCount()-1 && view.getLayoutParams().height == 0) {
        // we know how much height the prior rows take, so calculate the last row with that.
        int height = usedHeightForAndAfterDesiredRow();
        height = Math.max(0, parent.getHeight() - height);
        view.getLayoutParams().height = height;
    }
    return view;
}
```

This is in my adapter. It's a subclass of a merge adapter, but you can just put it in your code and substitute the super call with however you generate your rows.

the first if statement in getView() sets the layout params of a frame layout member var that is only intended for measuring, it has no parent view.

the second if statement calculates all the row heights for rows including and after the position of the row that I care about scrolling to the top. rowHeights is a SparseIntArray.

the last if statement assumes that there is one extra view with layout params already set at the bottom of the list of views whose sole intention is to be transparent and expand at will. the usedHeightForAndAfterDesiredRow call adds up all the precalculated heights which is subtracted from the parent view's height (with a min of 0 so we don't get negative heights). this ends up creating a view on the bottom that expands at will based on the heights of the other items, so a specific row can always scroll to the top of the list regardless of where it is in the list.

Comment: in `position >= mainRowPosition` what is `mainRowPosition` supposed to be?

Comment: Your solution might work for you, but misses crucial information to be of any use for others.
As Abhishek and Prakash already commented, what is measuringLayout and mainRowPosition?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you the [setSelectionFromTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelectionFromTop%28int,%20int%29) method of listview.

```
mListView.setSelectionFromTop(listItemIndex, 0);
```

Comment: I'm already using that and it works if there are enough cells below the desired row such that the row could scroll up there normally, but it doesn't force the row to the very top of the list if the user can't scroll it there on their own so that's not what I need.